# The meaning of key function in sort() and the meaning of np.argsort()

Tags: python

I want to sort a List and get a return of its indices.

So I did it in two ways, but both of them give me the wrong result. I don't know, what the problem with that.

For example:

```
myList = [2, 1, 7, 3, 6]
```

My goal is to get the result: [1, 0, 4, 2, 3]

So the first method:

```
np.array(myList).argsort()
```

But I got the wrong result:

```
Out: array([1, 0, 3, 4, 2])
```

the second method:

```
indices = range[5]
indices.sort(key=myList.__getitem__)
```

I got the same wrong result:

```
Out: [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]
```

I have no idea, why this happens?

Comment: For your example with `myList = [2, 1, 7, 3, 6]`, `argsort()` is providing the correct answer: `array([1, 0, 3, 4, 2])`. This translates to `1, 2, 3, 6, 7`. Your intended result of `[1, 0, 4, 2, 3]` would yield `1, 2, 6, 7, 3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's your original list `myList` sorted against your expected list of indices vs the two results you got:

Excepted:

```
>>> [myList[each] for each in [1, 0, 4, 2, 3]]
[1, 2, 6, 7, 3]
```

Results from your solutions:

```
>>> [myList[each] for each in [1, 0, 3, 4, 2]]
[1, 2, 3, 6, 7]
```

I think your solutions are correct and your expected list is incorrect.

**Update**

Base on the explanation of the expected result actually being the "ranks" of each item in the input, here's a solution:

```
myList = [2, 1, 7, 3, 6]

def get_rankings(list):
    return [sorted(list).index(each) for each in list]

print get_rankings(myList)
#[1, 0, 4, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Hi user3558083 and @chdorr: Thanks for the answer! But originally I really expect the result [1,0,4,2,3], because  in myList [2 -> the second smallest, 1-> the first smallest, 7-> the 5-th smallest , 3 -> the third smallest, 6 -> the 4-th smallest], so I get the result: [1,0,4,2,3].

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misunderstood the description of what argsort() does. This method returns an array, where the value at each index, is the index in the original array of the element that belongs there.

For example:

[2, 1, 7, 3, 6]

becomes:
[1, 0, 3, 4, 2]

as in:

[1] - value = 1

[0] - value = 2

[3] - value = 3

[4] - value = 6

[2] - value = 7

Comment: Thanks, Moshe Carmeli! This is just what I misunderstood!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for the answer. I think, I misunderstood the index. But originally I really want to have this result: [1,0,4,2,3], not [1,0,3,4,2]

for myList [2, 1, 7, 3, 6]

```
2 is the second smallest number, corresponds to 1
1 is the first smallest number, corresponds to 0
7 is the fifth smallest number, corresponds to 4
3 is the third smallest number, corresponds to 2
6 is the fourth smallest number, corresponds to 3
```

So, that is why I expect [1,0,4,2,3]

I think, now I can get the result, just do following steps:

```
indices = np.array(myList).argsort()
[indices.tolist().index(i) for i in range(5)]
```

So I will get the expected result: [1,0,4,2,3]